# Increasing counter does not change value of other variable

Tags: javascript

why would the [counter] variable value used in other variable not change as the counter value changes? Is it something to do with the reference?

```js
var counter = 0;

var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[counter].getElementsByClassName("pizza");

console.log(allFields);

counter++;

console.log(allFields); // expected result is to have 2 pizza elements.
```

```html
<div class="test">
 <div class="pizza"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
 <div class="pizza"></div>
 <div class="pizza"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
 <div class="pizza"></div>
 <div class="pizza"></div>
  <div class="pizza"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
 <div class="pizza"></div>
 <div class="pizza"></div>
  <div class="pizza"></div>
  <div class="pizza"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you run that code, `counter` is 0.  It is not incremented until later.

Comment: Yeah, you should be looping through the length of the selected elements

Comment: Oh, actually, "Is it something to do with the reference?"  yes.  It is an integer so it is passed by value and the object is saved at that point.  When you increment later the original value is unchanged.

Comment: How to effectively increase the counter to change the `allFields` accordingly?

Comment: Leave `document.getElementsByClassName('test')` as an array and then access it when you need it via the `counter` index.  As soon as you save one element of that array to a variable, it is saved and will not update the way you are wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've assigned fields to `allFields` with `counter = 0` - they'll not change anymore - you have to reassign this variable again.

I'd suggest you to create it as a function:

```
var allFields = function(i) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName('test')[counter].getElementsByClassName("pizza");
}

var counter = 0;
console.log(allFields(counter));

counter++;
console.log(allFields(counter));
```

The other, better way is to make a loop, like:

```
for (var i = 0, i < 2; i++) {
  var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[i].getElementsByClassName("pizza");

  console.log(allFields);
}
```

Comment: His misunderstanding is that he thought that the `counter` was by reference so when he increments it then does another `console.log` he expected the original object to change.

Comment: 'The other, better way' is hardcoding ?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you set

`var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[counter]`

the object is created.  You cannot then dynamically change the object by just changing `counter`.  If you want to be able to do this then just save

`var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName('test')`

and use the `[counter]` when you need.